# Passing arguments with remoteFunctions onFailure

Tags: grails

With remoteFunction, I cannot pass arguments with onFailure method.

The standard arguments – xhr, status, error are undefined.

This is a portion of my code:

```
onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'selectEntity',
                       onSuccess: 'selectEntity_onsuccess(data)',
                       onFailure: 'selectEntity_onfailure()')}"

function selectEntity_onfailure(xhr, status, error) {   
  alert(error);
}
```

I tried to add the arguments on the call but then it did not find the function.
onFailure: 'selectEntity_onfailure(xhr, status, error)

Grails 2.3.5